# use std::bind to bind a bool member function inside std::any_of?

Tags: c++11

(this is a contrived example)

I want to compute `std::is_any` of `empty()` on a `std::vector<std::vector>`.

I can do it with lambda expressions:

```
std::any_of(vecs.begin(), vecs.end(), 
    [](std::vector<T> const &v) { return v.empty(); });
```

that lambda looks needlessly ugly to me.  Is there a way to use `std::bind` in this situation instead?

Comment: I'm sure the `bind` would look uglier.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but in this situation can't you just pass a pointer to the `empty` method directly? It has the right prototype, after all.

Comment: You might be able to use `std::mem_fn` to wrap it as well.

Comment: @Dave no, `std::vector::empty()` expects a `this` pointer, not a reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you asked for `std::bind`, but you can do the same thing with `std::mem_fn` with very little hassle:

```
std::any_of(begin(vecs), end(vecs), std::mem_fn(&std::vector<T>::empty));
```

(still not as clean as the lambda though, in my opinion.)

Comment: This is what i was looking for.  I agree it's ugly but in different ways; the extra `return` in the lambda rubs me the wrong way for some reason.  Anyway I'm really happy that C++11 has these features, and I use them every day, but the syntax is hard to swallow compared to languages like Lisp and Python...

Comment: I agree. When working in C++ I miss Haskell. But C++11 (and 14) are making things much nicer.

Comment: For sure.  Although, the template error messages and layers of incomprehensible `functional.h` on the debugger call stack make it hard to sell this stuff to the old-timers that I work with.  I am looking forward to Rust, need to learn it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

[Challenge accepted](http://ideone.com/VVKgWI):

```
std::any_of(vecs.begin(), vecs.end(), 
    std::bind(&std::vector<T>::empty, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following uses `std::mem_fn` instead of `std::bind`, tested with GCC-4.9:

```
std::any_of(vecs.begin(), vecs.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::vector<T>::empty));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that this could be enough but would we use uglier syntax anyway

```
bool is_empt(vector<int>&  p){
    return p.empty();
}
int main (){
    // placeholders and bind function TRY 
    vector<vector<int>> v ;
    v.resize(5);
    auto fn = std::bind(is_empt , placeholders::_1);
    if (std::any_of(all(v) , [fn] (std::vector<int>  &v1) {return fn(v1);}))
        cout << "True\n";
    return 0;
}
```